# Split records into 2 columns based on record count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to select records from a single table. I have two columns to show the records.

I have to split the records based on the count. That is, I need to part the records into 20 rows for each section.

Additionally, in the event that I have more than 40 records, it needs to show the records in column 1.

Please refer the attached screenshot:

[image]

Records should be like this:

[image]

I have tried the below query in a stored procedure, but looks like I'm missing something. If the record count greater than 40, it's not retrieving as expected.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
CREATE proc mytest2
AS
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test1') IS NOT NULL
       DROP TABLE #test1

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test2') IS NOT NULL
       DROP TABLE #test2 

    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rno) 'rno',
        Reg, SerialNo  
    INTO 
        #test1 
    FROM
        (SELECT
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) 'rno',
             Reg, SerialNo  
         FROM
             tRe) AS c
    WHERE
        rno % 20 = 0

    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rno) 'rno1',            
        Reg AS Reg1, SerialNo AS SerialNo1 
    INTO
        #test2 
    FROM
        (SELECT
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) 'rno',
             Reg, SerialNo  
         FROM
             tRe) AS c
    WHERE
        rno % 20 <> 1

    SELECT * 
    FROM #test1 a 
    FULL OUTER JOIN #test2 b ON a.rno = b.rno1

     ------


EXEC mytest2
```

Comment: Hi create paramters for your page, and construct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your where condition to :
For First Query :

```
 WHERE (rno % 20 > 0 AND (rno / 20) % 2 = 0)  OR     (rno % 20 = 0 AND (rno / 20) % 2 = 1)
```

For Second Query :

```
 WHERE (rno % 20 > 0 AND (rno / 20) % 2 = 1)   OR    (rno % 20 = 0 AND (rno / 20) % 2 = 0)
```

That is to say Your Query Will be:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #test1

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #test2 

SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY rno ) 'rno' ,
        Reg ,
        SerialNo
INTO    #test1
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY EmployeeId ) 'rno' ,
                    Reg ,
                    SerialNo
          FROM      tRe
        ) AS c
WHERE   ( rno % 20 > 0
          AND ( rno / 20 ) % 2 = 0
        )
        OR ( rno % 20 = 0
             AND ( rno / 20 ) % 2 = 1
           )

SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY rno ) 'rno1' ,
        Reg AS Reg1 ,
        SerialNo AS SerialNo1
INTO    #test2
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY EmployeeId ) 'rno' ,
                    Reg ,
                    SerialNo
          FROM      tRe
        ) AS c
WHERE   ( rno % 20 > 0
          AND ( rno / 20 ) % 2 = 1
        )
        OR ( rno % 20 = 0
             AND ( rno / 20 ) % 2 = 0
           )

SELECT  *
FROM    #test1 a
        FULL OUTER JOIN #test2 b ON a.rno = b.rno1
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your time. It's working as expected. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much simpler code to achieve the same (you don't need to use temp tables, you can create a CTE with a row-numbering function and then refer to it twice):

```
WITH
    CTE AS (
        SELECT
            Reg, SerialNo, 
            rn = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Reg) - 1) / 20 + 1,
            rn2 = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Reg)) % 20
        FROM
            [tRe]
    )

SELECT 
    a.Reg, a.SerialNo, b.Reg, b.SerialNo
FROM 
    CTE a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    CTE b ON a.rn2=b.rn2 AND a.rn=b.rn-1
WHERE
    a.rn % 2 = 1
```